# Animation between hashtag-changes in iron:router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

On my website I navigate in my navbar between my-website/#about and my-website/#contact

With the new version of iron:router the router jumps automatically to the according anchors, but I want to add an animation between these two routes instead of a hard jump that iron:router provides.

Any ideas where to hook in?

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a hidden `Router._scrollToHash` method in `iron:router` that is called when you click on an anchor with a hash (`#id`), you can override the default behavior to animate smoothly from the current location to the element using this code :

```
Router._scrollToHash = function(hash) {
  var section = $(hash);
  if (section.length) {
    var sectionTop = section.offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: sectionTop
    }, "slow");
  }
};
```

Don't hesitate to dive into `iron:router` code when stumbling upon problems like this one, the source is very readable.

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/e403a72c596bc1f67dc635f07c742122edf29202/lib/router_client.js#L153